# Query utilizando "select" e "joins" com activerecord em Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Preciso fazer um relatório e tenho a seguinte *query*:

```
Deducao.joins(:prestador)
           .select('pessoas.razao_social, pessoas.qtd_min_mensal, count(deducoes.id)')
           .group('deducoes.prestador_id')
           .having('count(deducoes.id) < pessoas.qtd_min_mensal')
```

Ele gera o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT 
      pessoas.razao_social, 
      pessoas.qtd_min_mensal, 
      count(deducoes.id) 
FROM 
      deducoes
INNER JOIN 
      pessoas ON pessoas.id = deducoes.prestador_id
GROUP BY 
      deducoes.prestador_id 
HAVING 
      count(deducoes.id) < pessoas.qtd_min_mensal
```

O Sql gerado está correto, e se executo no *mysql* retorna o esperado. Mas ao executar no *activerecord* ele retorna `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Deducao id: nil>, #<Deducao id: nil>]>`. Por que ele retorna `id: nil` em vez dos campos que especifiquei no select `.select('pessoas.razao_social, pessoas.qtd_min_mensal, count(deducoes.id)')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele somente não mostra o valor das colunas que precisa por não existir um model nesse formato.

Tente da seguinte maneira: Adicione um alias para `count(deducoes.id) as qtd`

Então execute em seu console:

```
Deducao.joins(:prestador)
       .select('pessoas.razao_social, pessoas.qtd_min_mensal, count(deducoes.id) as qtd')
       .group('deducoes.prestador_id')
       .having('count(deducoes.id) < pessoas.qtd_min_mensal').first.qtd
```

Verás que o valor que precisa retornou.

Dá para simplificar um pouco também da seguinte maneira:

```
Pessoa.joins(:deducoes).select([:razao_social, :qtd_min_mensal, 'count(deducoes.id) as qtd']).group(:id).having('count(deducoes.id) < qtd_min_mensal')
```